# Generate signed APK - No product flavor defined

Tags: android, apk

[image]

I want to "Generate signed APK", but strangely, it says, that I've no product flavor defined, which is not true:

Whole Gradle file:

This is first time I saw something like this, so I've came here to look for an answer from someone more experienced.

Comment: Please, read this carefully https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants

Comment: @PeteWonder - Did you find a solution to this? I'm running into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to to create a `flavorDimensions` in your build.gradle (Module:app)

As GoRoS mentioned, this information in available [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants?utm_source=android-studio#product-flavors)